# chainlink price feeds

Tags: chainlink, usdt

fellow blockchain devs.  I want to get the price of usdt into my contract but I want to use Chainlink price feeds. the contract is going to be deployed on the bsc network
I want to know if it is possible to deploy chainlink price feeds on bsc network and if possible how do I go about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to use Chainlink Price Feeds on the BNB Chain.

To find the contract addresses of USDT pairs on the Chainlink Docs page, you can visit the following link: https://docs.chain.link/data-feeds/price-feeds/addresses?network=bnb-chain#BNB%20Chain%20Mainnet

Here is a sample contract that fetches the price of a pair using Chainlink Price Feeds: https://docs.chain.link/data-feeds/examples#reading-data-feeds-on-chain. You can modify the data feed address to the USDT pair from the BNB Chain.

Here is a detailed tutorial: https://docs.bnbchain.org/docs/link/

I hope this helps! Let me know if you have any further questions.